# 97 model Honda civic and battery drain

Tags: honda, civic, battery-drain, break-in

I do not use my Honda frequently, may be 2 or 3 times a month. The Battery is just about 7-8 months old from Costco.
I had last used the car on (I guess) Sunday. May be drive for about 30min total. While starting the car I did Not feel any sluggishness or problem cranking, it was smooth. But the next Saturday I found the Battery totally dead! 
What I also observed on Saturday, someone may have broken into the car (Has happened in past twice), the small side Panel near drivers left leg was loosely in place and the plastic pin that hold it in place were broken. I have not checked all the fuses but looks like all are in place.
Had warranty on battery so got a new one. Did inform the person at return counter, who suggested that the thief may have left the cabin light on. May be, I have not check it. But can it totally discharge the battery in 6 days?
Also want to ask is, if it is possible to check how much current is drawn when I install the battery, idle case (not trying to start motor) with a standard multimeter ? Not sure how much the rush current is ? My multimeter max range is 10Amp. Want to see if the wires are messed up causing the battery drain.
Next question is how much current should I expect ?
Just an FYI, Someone had left a note 2 weeks back intending to buy the car, not sure if they are looking for discounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**But can it totally discharge the battery in 6 days?**  A small bulb on constantly will drain a fully charged battery in a matter of days.

**Is it possible to check how much current is drawn with a standard multi-meter?**  Yes if the meter has an amp meter function.

**Next question is how much current should I expect?** Normal current draw is under 50 milli-amps with all switches off and the key out of the car.

Comment: Thanks Fred! Just to update all, someone had messed with the wiring causing the tail lights to be ON, even if the key is removed.

Answer (score 0):

A charge on a battery is a bit like a bank account. Driving for 30 minutes does not really charge it much and using it 2 or 3 times a month doesn't help either. A charge cycle is like a deposit and a discharge cycle is like a withdrawal. If you only add a bit of charge and have a long term term discharge your battery will go dead. I recommend investing in a battery tender (a very low amperage charger) that will keep your battery happy and fully charged.

In regard to your question about battery drain you can do what I once did years ago to test. I disconnected both terminals of the battery and connected a battery charger to the positive and negative wires (not to the battery) and plugged it in. If everything is good there should be no reading on the meter. This probably not the way the pros would do it but if you are careful it will work.